# Notepad++ Bookmark Lines, Advanced Search and Replace, Alternative Software Native to Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: wine, alternative, notepadqq

I am in the process of moving completely from Windows to Ubuntu. One of my favourite Software in Notepad++. I know it is possible to install it in Ubuntu with wine but I would like something native to Linux if possible.

One of the things that I use the most is Search for a term and bookmark the lines where this term is located. Then I use the "Paste to replace bookmarked Lines" function to get rid of this lines with a new text.

Is there a software capable to bookmark lines with the search function as Notepad++ does. Maybe notepadqq can but I dont know how...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For those in need of Notepad++

```
sudo snap install notepad-plus-plus
```

I now prefer to use KATE as I'm using Kubuntu.

It doesn't have the bookmarks option but you can do archive similar results by using regular expressions easily.

Other advance users should probable give VIM a try.

Intermediate users should go with ATOM, SUBLIME, or Microsoft Visual Studio.